# Updating hash key or sort key in dynamodb table creates 2 events in dynamo streams

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am using dynamodb streams to capture changes in the table. I have set the trigger to a lambda function. Insert and delete are working as expected but while updating specifically the hash key or sort key of any document it creates 2 events REMOVE and INSERT. That leads lambda function to process two events instead of one. How can I configure it to send only one event as MODIFY. Or how can I identify REMOVE and INSERT belongs to the same operation?
Also, one more problem with this is as I have set batch size and batch window. If the batch size is full, it is possible events come in different batches which will lead to inconsistency.

I tried to merge REMOVE and INSERT event by identifying consecutive sequence numbers. But sometimes they have consecutive sequence numbers and sometimes not.

Comment: Those are not modifications, those are deletions and insertions. That is how the database works. What are you doing with those events that it is problem to deal with them correctly?

Comment: I want to sync the data with elasticsearch. It results in 2 operations on elasticsearch instead of one MODIFY operation.

Comment: So? *How* are you syncing data with elasticsearch? Why is it a problem that you delete and insert data? They have different composite primary keys.

Comment: You can't update key attributes. See the note at [AttributeValueUpdate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValueUpdate.html). These are two different items: one deleted, one inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are updating keys in DynamoDB, as that is a forbidden operation, I assume you are using some sort of wrapper or third party library.

##### [AttributeValueUpdate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValueUpdate.html)

> You cannot use UpdateItem to update any primary key attributes. Instead, you will need to delete the item, and then use PutItem to create a new item with new attributes.

As you cannot update keys, your library is performing 2 operations which is a Delete (REMOVE) and a Put (INSERT/MODIFY), and this would be as expected.

While you cannot merge the events, you could use [Lambda Event Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html) to only listen to INSERT/MODIFY events.